# Listen to UDP message in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a software which sends/broadcasts UDP message over port 4747 and I want to get those messages on my C# application. I already used Microsoft Network Monitor and captured those UDP messages, but tried a bunch of stuff on my C# program and could not get any of those messages.
The message log in NetworkMonitor is like:
88922   00:46:57 14/11/2013 862.7592038     MM-B6DD62A  224.74.74.74    UDP UDP:SrcPort = 1053, DstPort = 7474, Length = 15 {UDP:1001, IPv4:984}

The message is being sent from one computer in network to other computers.

I was expecting some thing as simple as:

```
UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(7474);
udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
 public void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting some thing...");
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7474);
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

could solve my problem, but is not capturing any thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a broadcast packet? You may need to set EnableBroadcast to true on the UdpClient

Comment: Destination address is multicase (this is what I see in network monitor tool). I tried EnableBroadcast, no luck...

Comment: Yeah, multicast. You probably need to call JoinMulticastGroup (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fxkak8t(v=vs.100).aspx) with the 224.74.74.74 address. I've never tried this, however, just going by the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a multicast group will only work with IPv6, which IPAddress.Any is not so that will not work. What broadcast address are you using? 255.255.255.255 tends not to work as often software, devices and firewalls indiscriminately drop such broad broadcasts, however using broadcasting to a more specific subnet usually works, e.g.:

```
192.168.255.255.
```